# How to plot a bar plot as a function of x?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I want to make multiple bar plots but as a function of say altitude. I have several 2d arrays with numbers between 0 and 10. I want to count the frequency of the numbers for A, B, C, D, and E and plot a bar plot. Essentially I want to show a bar plot stacked but on the same plot. I am ok with another kind of plot to show this data but i could only think of bar plot. Any ideas how I would go about doing this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.random.randint(10, size=(11,11))
b = np.random.randint(10, size=(11,11))
c = np.random.randint(10, size=(11,11))
d = np.random.randint(10, size=(11,11))
e = np.random.randint(10, size=(11,11))

t = np.arange(0,11)
a_counts = np.array([])
for num in t:
    cnt = (a == num).sum()/a.size
    a_counts = np.append(a_counts, cnt)

b_counts = np.array([])
for num in t:
    cnt = (b == num).sum()/b.size
    b_counts = np.append(b_counts, cnt)

c_counts = np.array([])
for num in t:
    cnt = (c == num).sum()/c.size
    c_counts = np.append(c_counts, cnt)

d_counts = np.array([])
for num in t:
    cnt = (d == num).sum()/d.size
    d_counts = np.append(d_counts, cnt)

e_counts = np.array([])
for num in t:
    cnt = (e == num).sum()/e.size
    e_counts = np.append(e_counts, cnt)

comb =  {10:a_counts,20:b_counts,30:c_counts,40:d_counts,50:e_counts}
comb_df = pd.DataFrame(comb)

comb_df.plot.bar()
```

[image]

[image: This image is for illustration purposes. I am looking for a plot similar to this. The bars represent the frequency of the counts.]

Comment: Where is your code attempt to plot the graph? The code snippet shown just initialize a bunch of variables.

Comment: Updated the code with the plot I got.

Comment: What is `t` in your code?

Comment: Sorry i was working in jupyter and forgot to copy paste. I edited the code.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the desired output? I'm not sure if I got it right yet.

Comment: Hi. I added an image to show what kind of result I am after. This was not created by me.